# Why are cells needed when dealing with closures in Python?

Tags: python, closures, python-internals

I understand that in the following code:

```
a = 10
b = a
id(a) == id(b)  # True
```

`a` and `b` are labels that point to the same object in memory.

When returning a closure from a function, why are cells needed? Couldn't the returned closure's free variables just be new labels that point to the same object as the parent's variables? For instance, in the following example:

```
def outer():
  x = 10
  def inner():
    print(x)
  return inner
fn = outer()
fn()  # 10
```

In other words, why do I need (diagram following, not code):

```
outer.x -> cell -> obj(10)
inner.x -> cell -> obj(10)
```

and not have (diagram following, not code):

```
outer.x -> obj(10)
inner.x -> obj(10)
```

? What did this implementation try to avoid?

Comment: What are these cells? Can you please post an actual function with closures to make it clear.

Comment: @sanyash I added an example.

Comment: `outer.x` is 10. what do you mean by `-> cell ->` notation?

Comment: @sanyash I am studying a course and it says that `outer.x` also points to the cell. Is this wrong? Even if it is (in which case I will update the question), the question is still valid, why can't `inner.x` point to the object directly?

Comment: Also, `outer.x` gives `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'x'`.

Comment: If you are studying a course, it is great, but other people here are not studying the same course as you.  We can't guess what exactly are you talking about if your currently posted code gives errors.

Comment: @sanyash `outer.x` is just meant as a notation to make clearer what I mean. It is not python code as neither are the `->` and `obj(10)`.

Comment: It would be much more clear if you use python code, not pseudo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need something that maintains a reference to the object *being referenced by the variable*, not that object itself. Consider the following case:

```
In [1]: def outer():
   ...:     x = 42
   ...:     def first():
   ...:         return x * 2
   ...:     def second():
   ...:         nonlocal x
   ...:         x = 0
   ...:         return x
   ...:     return first, second
   ...:

In [2]: f,s  = outer()

In [3]: f()
Out[3]: 84

In [4]: s()
Out[4]: 0

In [5]: f()
Out[5]: 0
```

Note, the cell values maintain consistency:

```
In [6]: f.__closure__
Out[6]: (<cell at 0x1055df890: int object at 0x101f00470>,)

In [7]: s.__closure__
Out[7]: (<cell at 0x1055df890: int object at 0x101f00470>,)

In [8]: f.__closure__[0].cell_contents
Out[8]: 0

In [9]: s.__closure__[0].cell_contents
Out[9]: 0
```

If you just had bare references to those objects, you couldn't maintain consistency.

Just some to expand, notice that there are specific bytecodes for manipulating free variable cells:

```
In [10]: import dis

In [11]: dis.dis(f)
  4           0 LOAD_DEREF               0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              4 BINARY_MULTIPLY
              6 RETURN_VALUE

In [12]: dis.dis(s)
  7           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              2 STORE_DEREF              0 (x)

  8           4 LOAD_DEREF               0 (x)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

These are distinct from the operations that manipulate local variables, aptly named "fast":

```
In [16]: dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (3)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3           4 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: I am impressed how you guessed what the OP talks about.